# unwanted random sharpness/smoothness,

Tags: mesh, vertices, edges

Right where the edges begin to bend they start to have an artifact, but only in a part of the whole edge... please see below
[image]

[image]

Comment: That is something that can't be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of blenders shading methods when you use a subsurface modifier

the loop cuts are so close together , so blender can't figure out how to shade it

a simple solution is to use less details (Loop cuts) and a better topology (Loop cuts that follows the bending of the car surface here)

so here it should going from one side and bending in a V shape to the other.
Also you don't need to use that much loop cuts. Instead depend on the subsurface modifier to create more detail

something like this

[image]

[image]

**Note** : I added the double close edges to make the edges appear sharper

I recommend the anvil tutorial of blender guru on YouTube he goes more on depth on this

Comment: Thank you so much thats excatly what I needed to understand :)

Comment: Happy to help. Consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem cause that would help me too

Comment: I did watch his tutorials yeah and they are great, but Im still trying to learn a good method that can make my loop cuts follow along the edge please let me know if you have anything on that thank you so much

Comment: I would recommend this topology guide by CGcookie [here](https://cgcookie.com/articles/guide-to-clean-topology)